# Problem when flat catalog product option 'yes/no' on getting brand attributes

Tags: product-attribute, product-collection, eav, flat-catalog

I am getting all brands in my magento.When Flat catalog product is set to No, it fine. When it is no i got different result than i expected.

**My Code**

```
$attribute_code = array('apparelbrand','bagbrand','beltbrand','jewelrybrand','shoebrand','watchbrand');
foreach($attribute_code as $attribute_code)
    {
        $options= Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code)->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
        foreach($options as $option)
        {   
            $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter($attribute_code, $option["value"])->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>1));
            if(count($collection->getAllIds())>0)//Checks whether the product exist for particular brand
            {   
                Mage::log($option["label"].":".count($collection->getAllIds()));
                $cat[strtoupper(substr($option["label"],0,1))][]=$option["label"];//creates the multi-dimensional array of brand value with the starting character as key
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code results as

**Flat Catalog Product = No**

```
brand1 : 2
brand2 : 5
brand6 : 5
.
.
etc..
```

**Flat Catalog Product = Yes**

```
brand1 : 2
brand2 : 5
brand3 : 128
brand4 : 128
brand5 : 128
brand6 : 5
.
.
etc..
```

Why the `count()` returns 128 instead count even the brand does not have that much products.What could be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value `128` is printer for a particular attribute, so that attribute option is `Used in Product Listing = No`, By changing this option makes my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is core Magento "feature" which makes non-flat attributes not working in `addAttributeToFilter()` filtering when you use simple form:

```
addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $value)
```

Try to change this to following form:

```
addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $attribute_code, 'eq' => $option["value"])))
```

Another thing which is not exactly related with your question, is that you could try to optimize your code - eg. change `count($collection->getAllIds())` calls to `$collection->getSize()`.